# Sphinx: How to autofunction autogenerated Functions

Tags: python, python-sphinx, docstring, auto-generate

I followed the Sphinx Tutorial including the following step: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/tutorial/automatic-doc-generation.html#.

In this step, my Python file *lumache* was autogenerated in api.rst and generated a general overview about functions & exceptions in lumache.py:

[image]

I wonder, if it is possible to display all functions with their respective parameters, return values, complete docstrings etc. like it is done via *.. autofunction*, instead of only their name and the first line of their docstring.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: You should add docstrings of your function first. 
can refer Numpy style or Google Stryle docstring comments

Comment: Docstrings are already added, as seen above.